# Facebook SDK 4.1.0 error "Umbrella header for module 'FBSDKCoreKit' does not include header 'FBSDKTestUsersManager.h'

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I just updated from Facebook SDK version 4 to 4.1.0.  After updating, I am now getting the following warning:

> Umbrella header for module 'FBSDKCoreKit' does not include header
>   'FBSDKTestUsersManager.h'

Does anyone have any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because Facebook either removed `FBSDKTestUsersManager.h` or forgot to add it to `FBSDKCoreKit.h`.  Adding the following line to `FBSDKCoreKit.h` should resolve your problem:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKTestUsersManager.h>
```

**Update - 1**

its fixed in sdk 4.2.0

Comment: So FB releases new versions of their SDK without even testing it, and I basically integrate non-tested code to my app. Really nice.

Comment: This has been fixed with Facebook SDK 4.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the "Bolts.framework" will resolve this issue.

Comment: it was SDK problem no need to add it :)